# Directing users to specific pages on login in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

In my current project in PHP and MySQL, I have a database of  two different user- students and teachers-.

When I enter the username and password, I want the system can differentiate the user is a student  or teacher so that it can direct the user to the related page. How can I do that in PHP?
Should I create 2 tables in the same database or  2 tables in a different database.

login.php

```
<?php 

session_start();

// variable declaration
$username = "";
$password ="";
$query = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

// connect to database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'loginstudent');

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {   
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header('location: student.html');

        }else {

            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)***

Comment: Always add `exit();` after the header command.

Comment: Use one table and add a column where you can designate student or teacher. When you select you can get the value in that column to make the decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this correctly you should add a column to your 'users' table. For this example I will call the column `user_type` and for each user I will store either 'student' or 'teacher'. Starting at the point where you have executed your query:

```
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results); // get an associative array from the row returned

if('student' == $row['user_type']) {
    header('Location: student.html');
    exit();
} elseif ('teacher' == $row['user_type']) {
    header('Location: teacher.html');
    exit();
} else {
    // not a valid user
    header('Location: register.html');
    exit();
}
```

**WARNING**
Under your original post I provided several comments concerning the safety of your code. You should read and follow all of those warnings and learn how to write safe code from the start.

Comment: I added user_type column. Where should  I indicate student or teacher? the type should be ENEM or varchar?

Comment: Use varchar for the `user_type`

Comment: Thanks  a lot for helping me. I made it thanks to you